Need help locating where global code is managed (for chatbot updating) on Craft CMS 3.4.30
We are trying to update our chatbot, and as someone who wasn't here when the Craft site was set up, I can't find where the current code is located. I feel like I checked all of the logical places, but still have no clue. We uses Craft CMS 3.4.30 - it's for our legacy product. https://2019.cirrusinsight.com/

What does your server's file structure look like? Craft can be installed just about anywhere relative to the site's public root, as long as you have the 'pointer' settings right in index.php.

Where are you looking for the code? Do you have the site running locally? It could have been included in a number of ways, as a Craft plugin (composer.json), or module, or as an NPM package (package.json), for example. Please describe what you have tried already.
